# ajax still loading in onclick submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have this code. my problem is when I check the checkbox is still
 refreshing and the scroll is going up and did not return in his
 position after submitting the page. Can any one help me? Sorry I'm new in ajax.

```
    <style>
        .container {
            border:2px solid #ccc;
            width:600px;
            height: 1000px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
    </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="ajaxtry.php" id="searchForm">
 <div id="Html2" style="position:absolute;left:0x;top:60px;width:250px;height:100px;z-index:12" class="container">
    <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
    <br>
    <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
    <br>
    <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
    <br>
    <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
    <br>
    <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
    <br>
    <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
    <br>
    <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
</form>
<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the actual result you are looking for? I can't see any input name with s and any html element with id conent. which you are using on your ajax code.

Comment: it all in one page sorry im newb

Comment: if you can show me the page content please.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/61nay9Lg/

Comment: ijust want the scroll bar return in its position after submitting the page